# get decendents in XML where specific element contains value

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Licenses>
  <License>
    <LicenseType>Temporary License</LicenseType>
    <BundleType>Line</BundleType>
    <Features>
      <Feature>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
      <Feature>
        <Name>EnhancedUserAccounts</Name>
        <LocalisedName>Enhanced User Accounts</LocalisedName>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
    </Features>
  </License>
  <License>
    <LicenseType>Temporary License</LicenseType>
    <BundleType>Line</BundleType>
    <Features>
      <Feature>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
      <Feature>
        <Name>EnhancedUserAccounts</Name>
        <LocalisedName>Enhanced User Accounts</LocalisedName>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
    </Features>
  </License>
</Licenses>
```

How to read the feature list into to IEnumerable if my BundleType = line

Comment: is your xml contains any  namespace like `xmlns`?

Comment: could you please share your full xml bcoz your xml nodes are disturbed?

Comment: could you please show me the parent node of `LicenseType`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using XDocument

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(XML)
```

or

```
var xDocument = XDocuemnt.Load(FilePath)
```

then:

```
xDocument.Descendants("LicenseType")
```

Which will get all nodes that descend from LicenseType

To test for that BundleType element you could do something like:

```
nodes.Where(n=>n.Element("BundleType") == "Line").Decesendants("Features")
```

which will get all Features where `<BundleType>` of the parent is "Line"

EDIT: As per comments, to get all features:

```
xDocument.Desecendants("Features")
```

That will get all `<Feature>` nodes under the `<Features>` Element

Comment: i have read the file using XDocument licenseFeatureDocument = XDocument.Load(path of the file ) but after reading i have to read the feature into the Ienumerable<Xelement> which contains the bundleType as Line

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are trying to say. do you want all features where `BundleType == Line` ?

Comment: <LicenseType>Temporary License</LicenseType>
    <BundleType>Line</BundleType>
    <Features>
      <Feature>
        <Name>CimCommsLegacy</Name>
        <LocalisedName>Obsolete Cimcomms devices</LocalisedName>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
      <Feature>
        <Name>EnhancedUserAccounts</Name>
        <LocalisedName>Enhanced User Accounts</LocalisedName>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>

Comment: Now i want to get the feature which is of bundle type == line

Comment: <LicenseType>Temporary License</LicenseType>
    <BundleType>Line</BundleType>
    <Features>
      <Feature>        
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
      <Feature>
        <Name>EnhancedUserAccounts</Name>
        <LocalisedName>Enhanced User Accounts</LocalisedName>
        <Value>Full</Value>
        <Status>Full Access</Status>
        <AccessLevel>Full</AccessLevel>
      </Feature>
  </Features>

Answer (score 0):

Use following based on the xml I updated on your posting :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication70
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("License").Where(x => (string)x.Element("BundleType") == "Line")
                .Select(x => x.Descendants("Feature").ToList()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```